# Помощь в регулярном выражении

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Задача следующая: есть текст, с помощью регулярных выражений найти и заменить следующую комбинацию символ #+любая цифра+денежный знак (прим. #23$) на 3 звёздочки (прим. ***). Обязательно, что бы данная комбинация была внутри слова.

Вот код:

```
string input = "Добро пожаловать в наш магазин, вот наши цены: " +
               "1 кг. яблок - 20 руб. " +
               "2 кг. апе#5$в - 30 руб. " +
               "0.5 кг орехо#44$в - 50 руб.";



string pattern = @"(?<=(#+\d+\p{Sc})).\s";
string replacement = "***";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex.Replace(input, replacement);
Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}",input);
Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```

С текущим кодом, меняет последний символ и пробел, мне же нужно, что бы наоборот, последний символ и пробел оставляло, а мою комбинацию меняло на звёздочки, пробовал паттерн делать в таком виде

```
string pattern = @"#+\d+\p{Sc}(?<=(.\s))";
```

Почему-то не получается. Подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: а зачем вообще конструкцию `?<=` используете? денежный знак - это всегда `$`? а также добавьте ожидаемый результат для приведенной строки

Comment: конструкцию ?<= использую для того, что бы при замене, этот участок не заменяло, но в тоже время, что бы в поиске он учавствовал. Денежный знак не всегд $, поэтому я и использую универсальную переменную \p{Sc}.

Comment: Ожидаемый результат: Добро пожаловать в наш магазин, вот наши цены: " +
               "1 кг. яблок - 20 руб. " +
               "2 кг. апе*******в - 30 руб. " +
               "0.5 кг орехо*******в - 50 руб.

Только звёздочек три, тут редактор, что-то своё придумывает, когда три пишешь, ну не суть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно, чтобы и слева, и справа от `#\d+\$` были символы слова:

```
string pattern = @"\b#\d+\p{Sc}\b";
```

или так:

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\w)#\d+\p{Sc}(?=\w)";
```

Если же нужно, чтобы символы слова были слева и/или справа:

```
string pattern = @"\b#\d+\p{Sc}|#\d+\p{Sc}\b";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, последний вариант подошел! Если можно, объясните, почему именно так?

Comment: `\b` срабатывает на границе слов (между `\w` и '\W` или наоборот). А так как и `#` и `\p{Sc}` входят в класс символов `\W` (не слово), то шаблон `\b#\d+\p{Sc}` ловит вашу комбинацию, перед которой будет `\w` (символ слова). Аналогично, шаблон `#\d+\p{Sc}\b` ловит вашу комбинацию, после которой будет символ слова. Я только объединил эти два шаблона оператором "или" `|`, получилось ловить вашу комбинацию, перед или после которой будет символ слова.

Comment: То же самое: `(?<=\w)#\d+\p{Sc}|#\d+\p{Sc}(?=\w)`.
Не знаю только, как не повторять шаблон для вашей комбинации дважды.

Comment: Ваш первый шаблон `(?<=(#+\d+\p{Sc})).\s` состоит из zero-width positive lookbehind assertion, после которой любой символ, затем пробельный символ. А так как она zero-width (matched substring is not included in the match result, то она и не заменяется. Заменяются только `.\s`.

Comment: Во втором шаблоне `#+\d+\p{Sc}(?<=(.\s))` почти правильно, но после вашей комбинации стоит zero-width positive lookbehind assertion `(?<=)`, которая смотрит _назад_ (влево) и найти пробел в вашей комбинации ну никак не может.

Comment: Всё по полочкам, спасибо!